# Include column names in Grails SQL query results

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a query that looks like this...

```
        def data = session.createSQLQuery("""SELECT
  a.id AS media_id,
  a.uuid,
  a.date_created,
  a.last_updated,
  a.device_date_time,
  a.ex_time,
  a.ex_source,
  a.sequence,
  a.time_zone,
  a.time_zone_offset,
  a.media_type,
  a.size_in_bytes,
  a.orientation,
  a.width,
  a.height,
  a.duration,
  b.id           AS app_user_record_id,
  b.app_user_identifier,
  b.application_id,
  b.date_created AS app_user_record_date_created,
  b.last_updated AS app_user_record_last_updated,
  b.instance_id,
  b.user_uuid
FROM media a, app_user_record b
WHERE a.uuid = b.user_uuid
LIMIT :firstResult, :maxResults """)
                .setInteger("firstResult", cmd.firstResult)
                .setInteger("maxResults", cmd.maxResults)
                .list()
```

The problem is the .list method returns an array that has no column names.  Does anybody know of a way to include/add the column names from a Grails native sql query.  I could obviously transform the results into a map and hard code the column names myself.

Comment: When you use `as` in the select query, cant you access that? For example: `data.each{println it.get('media_id')}` or `it['media_id']` so on and so forth.

Comment: I meant a way to dump the results to an array with a "header" row.  I have to write a lot of queries like this and having to manually insert  the name of each column by hand is slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)` for the query. This would result a map of entries.

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria

def query = """Your query"""
def data = session.createSQLQuery(query)
                .setInteger("firstResult", cmd.firstResult)
                .setInteger("maxResults", cmd.maxResults)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
                .list()

data.each{println it.UUID}
```

I tested it and realized that earlier I used to use the column number to fetch each field instead of the column name.

**NOTE**
Keys are upper case. so `ex_source` would be `EX_SOURCE` in the result map.